# Ad id from Google publisher tag

Tags: ads, google-publisher-tag

Is there anyway to find the id of an ad that has served from GPT?
The ad response contains `creativeId`, `campaignId`, etc. but I couldn't find anything related to the ad id

I tried reading the docs and ad manager help center issues but I couldn't find any answers

Comment: What do you call "ad id"?

Comment: @rabsom an unique identifier for an ad which remains the same across other websites.

Comment: ids being related to your GAM network, I dont think there are cross sites shared ids in direct campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Using the googletag.pubads() object, you  can retrieve the following informations for each defined slots :

- advertiserId
- campaignId
- companyId
- creativeId
- creativeTemplateId
- isBackfill
- lineitemId
- sourceAgnosticCreativeId
- sourceAgnosticLineItemId
- encryptedTroubleshootingInfo

See [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.responseinformation) for details.
To retrieve data from your first adslot in the page :

```
googletag.pubads().getSlots()[0].getResponseInformation()
```

Comment: I knew I can retrieve these props (as I said in my question "The ad response contains `creativeId`, `campaignId`, etc.", my question is about ad id